Episode identification of divorce confusion scene
I want to know the season and episode of Friends in which this scene occurred:
This scene was taken in Central Perk, where either Phoebe or Rachel is talking about some person, who just had divorce, and after hearing that conversation Joey suddenly shout at Ross saying: "What is wrong with you?" (Thinking that cause of divorce is Ross) and Ross looks at Joey with confusion. 

It's in the intro of The One That Could Have Been Part 1, episode 15 in season 6.

Rachel: Hey, you guys! Guess what? Barry and Mindy are getting a divorce!
Joey: (To Ross) What is the matter with you?!
Phoebe: No, Barry and Mindy!
Joey: Oh sorry, I hear divorce I immediately go to Ross.

The news leads the gang to wonder what would happen if they made different choices in life, which is the premise of this two-parter that takes place in a sort of alternative timeline.

Urgh, as much as I love Friends, those stupid alternate timeline episodes were an utter abomination.

@NapoleonWilson: I think they did only one of those.

Oh yeah.. two parts.. but still only 2.
